# Do we need the "divergence" tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management, tag-wikis, retagging

Currently, there exist a tag [divergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divergence), about which I'd like to know your opinion:

1. the tag has no usage guidance and no tag wiki. This means that users cannot know whether this tag is dedicated to "divergence" as opposed to "convergence" (of series, sequences, integrals), or rather to "divergence" as in "divergence of a vector field". In fact, this tag is currently used in both situations (with the majority of the questions using the first meaning)...
2. ...which brings us to: is it not redundant to use this tag for "divergence as opposed to convergence", given that we have the vastly more used tag [convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convergence) (8656 vs. 104 tagged questions for each)?

I suggest removing this tag altogether and retagging the questions about the divergence of vector fields with [vector-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vector-analysis).

Comment: I vote for retagging the questions about the divergence of vector fields, and then making [tag:divergence] a synonym of [tag:convergence].

Comment: Perhaps you should have used the [tag management thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22348/tag-management-2016) instead of asking a new question.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I tought about this, but in that tag answers may be given only as comments (with answers themselves being like new posts), which is weird. Also, that thread suffers from really poor visibility, maybe we should invent something like "pinning" (as done in discussion fora)?

Comment: A new answer will bump. In that since it gets new visibility. Re pinning  on can tag a Q as FAQ, which amounts to about that, but given  what I just said it feels not really needed in this case.

Comment: I agree with @Daniel on this matter.

Comment: Somewhat related: [How should questions about deciding convergence/divergence of a series be tagged?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/20959)

Comment: I have posted a (different) suggestion in the tag management thread for 2017 : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25694/tag-management-2017/26767#26767